# The cooking temperature 15 degree is consider as ...?

Tags: temperature

When we perform cooking on devices such as in the oven, the temperature is considered as the cooking temperature or the normal temperature?

For example, when I cook a potato in the oven in a temperature at 15 degree Celsius, is it the same than putting a potato in a room at a temperature of 15 degree Celsius?

Comment: I'm really not clear on what you're asking for here.  There is isn't some different temperature scale for ovens -- a degree celsius is a degree celsius.

Comment: I don't think it will cook at 15C. But if you put it in a room that was 150C, it would be the same as putting it in an oven that's 150C. Of course, if your oven has a convection fan, the very hot room would also need a fan to make it more equivalent. ;)

Comment: @FuzzyChef, Actually FustratedWithFormsDesigner had answered my question. At first, I was thinking that the 15 Degree Celsius in a room is different than the 15 Degree Celsius in a oven but FustratedWithFormsDesigner had enlighten me.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner, Please put your comment as answer and I will mark it correct. (By the way, actually I am trying out a slow cooking with a low temperature in a room)

Comment: @Anderson Karu, don't do that. You need a cooking temperature of at least 60°C to kill bacteria. I doubt you can keep a room that hot. If you leave food in a room which is 35°C, not only will in not get cooked, it is dangerous to eat.

Comment: @Anderson Karu: Done.

Comment: @rumtscho, +1 for pointing that there is no such thing as low temperature cooking (e.g. 15 degree) and require at least 60 degree to kill bacteria.

Comment: ... was the OP really thinking he could cook something at 15°C?

Comment: There are two kinds of "cooking" processes that could run at temperatures that low: chemical pickling/curing (as in the science of chemistry, not using stuff that comes in skull and crossbones jars. Eg salt and/or vinegar cured dishes, macerated fruit...), and fermentation of various kinds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it will cook at 15C. But if you put it in a room that was 150C, it would be the same as putting it in an oven that's 150C. Of course, if your oven has a convection fan, the very hot room would also need a fan to make it more equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

Cooking normally involves higher heat than you would feel comfortable in a room; the application of heat is what changes the molecular structure of food and kills bacteria, making it both tasty and safe to consume. There's otherwise no real magic to it: if it's a hot enough day outside, you can put a frying pan on the hot pavement in a parking lot and fry an egg in it as though it were on the stove. If for some reason the apocalypse was happening and it were 350F outside, you could bake a cake the same way. But you'd probably be dead.

Comment: +1 for pointing that there is no such thing as low temperature cooking (e.g. 15 degree).

Comment: I think dashboard cookies were an actual thing during a heatwave a few years ago?